# Is it possible to center the labels and data points between the ticks in a datetime xAxis for Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adaykin/QKw77/ which uses the datetime type for the xAxis. As you can see the data points in the line and the labels are on the tick marks and not between them. How can I change both the data points and the labels so that they are centered within a tick mark?

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {        
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            format: "{value:%Y-%m-%d}",

        },
        tickmarkPlacement: 'between'
    },
    yAxis: {

    },


    series: [
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, 1, 3),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7 // one day
    },
    {
        data: [50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, 1, 3),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7
    }
    ]
});
```

The data points and labels are centered between the tick marks when the xAxis is not using the datetime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [startOfWeek](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOfWeek)

```
xAxis: {       
    startOfWeek: 5,
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        format: "{value:%Y-%m-%d}",

    },
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QKw77/2/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This looks like it shifts the labels and ticks to the right, but unfortunately it doesn't put the data points and labels in between the ticks.

Comment: Unfortunalty this kind of solution is not supported.